# Keeping minor frame ticks after changing unit/scale of the axes

Tags: ticks, scaling, grid-lines

as the title says, I would like to find a way to keep the minor ticks after I change the unit/scale of an axis. For example:

```
a = 3.77551;
b = -3717;
p = p /. Solve[Log[p] == (a + b/t), p][[1]]
Plot[p, {t, 0, 1000}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

And modifying the ticks:

```
Plot[p, {t, 0, 1000}, Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> {{-273, -23, 227, 477, 727} + 273, {100, 75, 50, 25, 0}/
    100},
 FrameTicks -> {{Table[{i, ToString[ 100 i]}, {i, 0, 1, 1/4}], 
    Automatic},
   {Table[{i, ToString[ i - 273]}, {i, 0, 1000, 250}], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

I would like to find a way to include the minor ticks when I change the scale as well as possibly an easier way (shorter/more efficient) to realign the GridLines.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than muddle through the syntax for creating your own tick marks, here's a method to do this using the undocumented function `` Charting`FindTicks `` which has been used here before.  The way this function works is you feed it the original range your data goes over, and the new range you want the scaled values to range over.  Then I use a helper function to strip the ticks of their labels,

```
ticksWithoutLabels[or_, vi_] := Select[
   Charting`FindTicks[or, vi][##],
   (Length@# > 2 &)] &

Plot[p,{t,0,1000},
    GridLines->{Range[-1000,1000,200]+273, Range[0,1,.2]},
    Frame->True,
    FrameTicks->{
        {Charting`FindTicks[{0,1},{0,1000}],
        ticksWithoutLabels[{0,1},{0,1000}]},
        {Charting`FindTicks[{0,1000},{0-273,1000-273}],
        ticksWithoutLabels[{0,1000},{0-273,1000-273}]}
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You do still have to write the `GridLines` specifications using the original scale though.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've been a huge help.